# How do you add plugin buttons to the left of the default buttons in a redactor editor's toolbar?

Tags: redactor, redactor.js

I'm working with a redactor editor that uses several default buttons and a number of plugin buttons (e.g. 'fontfamily', 'fontcolor', 'fontsize'). I'd like to re-order the buttons so that the plugin buttons can be placed before (i.e. to the left of) the default buttons. This does not appear to be natively supported by the redactor API. How can I do this?

Answer (score 0):

You will need to edit the plugin code, here is a very basic example of a plugin:

```
if (!RedactorPlugins) var RedactorPlugins = {};

RedactorPlugins.custombutton = function()
{
    return {
        init: function()
        {
            var button = this.button.add('custom-button', 'Add Button');
            this.button.addCallback(button, this.custombutton.show);
        },
        show: function()
        {
            console.log('myplugin show');
    };
};
```

You need to tweak this line (below), it will be within the init method.

```
var button = this.button.add('custom-button', 'Add Button');
```

this.button.add insert the button at the end of the toolbar by default. You can read more about the other options here http://imperavi.com/redactor/docs/api/button/

But to add at the start you will want addFirst:

```
var button = this.button.addFirst('custom-button', 'Add Button');
```